# Sanity.io fetch function running infinitely

Tags: react-native, expo, sanity

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Memory from "../component/Memory";
import sanityclient from "../memories-20/sanityclient";
const Memories = () => {
  const [memories, setMemories] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(0);

  const batchOfMemories = memories.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 3);

  const fetchData = () => {
    sanityclient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == "memory"] | order(date desc) {
                ...,
            }`
      )
      .then((data) => {
        setMemories(data);
        console.log(memories);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }),
    [];

  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center bg-transparent justify-center">
      <View>
        <View className="flex items-center w-full h-[90%]">
          {!isLoading ? (
            <View>
              {batchOfMemories.map(
                (memory, index) =>
                  <Memory />
              )}
            </View>
          ) : (
            <Loading />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Memories;
```

I'm using React Native - Expo with Sanity.io

The problem is that the fetchData function runs infinitely which is making the API Request count massive.

How do I make it so that it only runs on page load?
or if possible, runs only if there is change?

Comment: Check the syntax of useEffect.

Comment: Even when i put the fetchData(); call function outside of the useEffect and remove the useEffect entirely, it still calls the API infinitely

Answer (score 0):

I solved it simply just by adding a if check before running the fetch

```js
const fetchData = () => {
  if (!memories.length) {
    sanityclient
      .fetch(`*[_type == "memory"] | order(date desc) { ..., }`)
      .then((data) => {
        setMemories(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    console.log("fetch");
  } else {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
};
```

Not the best solution, the function still runs infinitely but atleast the API doesn't get called because the variable already has data in it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the `fetchData` function runs infinitely because you write wrong `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}),
  [];
```

Correct code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```